# Capturing current_user.id saving deeply nested records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets say I have a working form that looks like the following

```
=form_for @survey do |f|
  =f.text_field :name
  =f.fields_for :questions do |question_fields|
    =question_fields.text_field :question_text
      =question_fields.fields_for :answers do |answer_fields|
        =answer_fields.text_field :answer_text
```

Because different parts of the form can be added and updated by different users I need a way to get the user_id into each model before it is saved.  I realize it is not mvc compliant to be able to access current_user inside the model, that being said I am left without a solution.

If I was only saving one object it would be simple enough to assign the current_user.id to the object in the controller, but given the deeply nested nature of this form that starts to look like an ugly solution.

Is there an expert/railsy way to handle this?

Rails 3.2, devise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't each of the objects simply steal the `user_id` from their "parent" relationship? This is a common pattern:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :assign_user_id

protected
  def assign_user_id
    # Don't attempt if the question is not defined,
    # or the user_id field is already populated.
    return unless (self.question or self.user)

    self.user_id = self.question.user_id
  end
end
```

This involves a bit of additional database activity to resolve the answer for each question, as creating it in a scope is not sufficient, but it makes it pretty much fool-proof.

What you probably want to do is stuff in the `user_id` parameter when creating each record. This means your `create` call needs to merge in a `:user_id` key where required. The nested helper doesn't do this by default, though, so if you're using that you may just leave it up to the assign method.